# Not getting any output from c++ program

Tags: c++

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>


void print(std::vector <int> const& a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << a.at(i) << " ";
    }
}

std::vector<int> factors(int n) {
    std::vector<int> vec = {};
    for (int i = 0; i < round(sqrt(n)); i++) {
        if (size(factors(i)) == 0) {
            vec.push_back(i);
        }
        std::cout << i;
    }
    return vec;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec = factors(600851475143);
    print(vec);
    }
```

This is my C++ code for [Project Euler #3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3).

New to C++, so my code might be completely wrong syntactically, however I am not getting any build errors (using Visual Studio).

Not getting any output however. I understand this could be my fault, and the program might just be running extremely slow. But I programmed this in python using the same iterative method and it worked perfectly with a fast runtime.

Edit:

I am however getting this message in the console:

```
D:\RANDOM PROGRAMMING STUFF\PROJECTEULER\c++\projecteuler3\x64\Debug\projecteuler3.exe (process 13552) exited with code 0.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

Comment: Do you get output from a HelloWorld which you build and run the same way?

Comment: Yes, was also getting output before when printing different things. just no output for this specific program.

Comment: How do you make `std::cout` work without `#include <iostream>`?

Comment: i do have #include <iostream>, just accidentally didnt highlight that line when copying code in, my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

If you enable your compiler warnings, you should see an overflow warning

> prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
> prog.cc:23:36: warning: overflow in conversion from 'long int' to 'int' changes value from '600851475143' to '-443946297' [-Woverflow]
> 23 |     std::vector vec = factors(600851475143);

so what gets passed to `factors` is not `600851475143` but `-443946297`

Comment: should I then define the vectors with a different data type?

Comment: I wonder how much woe could have been avoided if only compilers were in the habit of *enabling all warnings possible unless explicitly disabled*....

Comment: @bbqribs: For any kind of program dealing with numerics, you need to be aware of the value range those numbers can conceivably be in, make sure that the possible numbers fit into the data types used, and ensure that inputs *outside* that value range are dealt with before they get processed (as in, "sorry, can't work on numbers that large, please try again.". The `int_leastN_t` types from [`<cstdint>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) are commonly used for this purpose.

Comment: i looked up data types and am now using something called a "unsigned long long int", and I am now getting output. However the output is definitely wrong. Is there anything else wrong with the code, specifically with the factors() function?

Answer (score 1):

Of course Gaurav has given the correct answer. This is how to fix it, change from int to unsigned long long, to allow for the biggest integers possible that are supported without any external libraries

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>



void print(std::vector<int> const& list){
    for( auto const& item : list){
        std::cout << item << "\n";
    }
}

std::vector<int> factors(unsigned long long n) {
    std::vector<int> vec = {};
    for( int i = 0; i < std::round(std::sqrt(n)); ++i ){
        if( factors(i).empty() ) {
            vec.push_back(i);
        }
        //std::cout << i << ", ";
    }
    return vec;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec = factors(600851475143ULL);
    print(vec);
}
```

I have also done some other minor changes:

- Change the foor loop of print to a rang-based for loop
- Added a delimeter i printing
- added std:: namespace to functions
- replaced size(vec) == 0 with empty to improve readability

Another good habit is to compile with `-Wall` to enable more warnings and `-Werror` so you are actually forced to take care of all warnings instead of brushing them off.

Comment: I ran this code and it's outputting every number in order. So obviously something was terribly wrong with my code at the start. Just wondering, does this code run correctly for you?

Comment: nevermind, that was because i was doing std::cout << i, completely my fault

Comment: @bbqribs not entirely, I actually accidentally removed something from your code. I updated the code accordingly and commented out the `std::cout << i`. still, it does not appear fully functional yet.

Comment: when I ran the code with std::cout << i<< ", " it is outputting a repeated series of (seemingly random) numbers. so could it be an issue with the for loop? not properly incrementing i?

Comment: @bbqribs that is because you are calling factors recursively. So while waiting for the output of the first call, outputs from the recursive calls are made.